# How to reset several counters in java/android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-view

I have six counters that need to be reset at a certain point of the program. I guess it is possible with a for loop? Thanks in advance

```
int counters[] = {score,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5};
for(int i=0; i<counters.length; i++) {
    findViewById(counters[i]); //...and it resets them all?
}
```

Comment: Yes, if `score,count1` is equals `R.id.<id_of_view_to_reset>`

Comment: How about you try it yourself? ;) Afaict it should work yes

Comment: ok, thanks for the hint Andriy

Answer (score 0):

```
score = R.id.score;
count1 = R.id.count1;
//etc.
```

If your integers has these numbers of resources, yes it is going to work.